# Using LibreOffice/OpenOffice from JAVA to convert File Formats

Tags: java, openoffice.org, libreoffice, uno

I'm using LibreOffice4.0 UNO to convert files. I managed converting between doc and docx, from xlsx to xls and from docx to doc, but I'm having trouble finding the FilterName value for XLSX and PPTX.

```
propertyValues[0] = new PropertyValue();
propertyValues[0].Name = "FilterName";
propertyValues[0].Value = "...";

for doc I used:  "swriter: MS Word 97";
for docx I used: "Office Open XML Text";
for xls I used:  "swriter: MS Excel 97";
for ppt I used:  "swriter: MS PowerPoint 97";
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the question exactly? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For XLSX you can use either `Calc MS Excel 2007 XML` or `MS Excel 2007 XML`.

I also found this for OpenOffice but I'm not sure if it works for your case:

```
DOCX - MS Word 2007 XML 
XLSX - Calc MS Excel 2007 XML 
PPTX - Impress MS PowerPoint 2007 XML
```

There is a **BIG** list [`here`](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=71294)